# Custom Session ID generation in Jboss 5

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, sessionid, jsessionid

Is there a way to use custom session ID generator in Jboss 5?

The reason I need this: my company application needs to pass penetration test and for that it needs to have session IDs, which "are 128 bit in length and comprised of random values".

Answer (score 0):

JBoss 5 satisfies that requirement out of the box: [SessionIDGenerator.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.jbossas/jboss-as-tomcat/5.1.0.GA/org/jboss/web/tomcat/service/session/SessionIDGenerator.java/).